# In need of a deterministic uniform distribution using C++11

Tags: c++11, random, distribution, deterministic

I'm using C++11's random library for producing deterministic random values, I need to restrict the output to various ranges and naturally used `std::uniform_int_distribution` but much to my dismay the specification gives library implementations too much freedom and output differs between i.e. X86-64 Linux and X86 Windows 7.

Is there any option besides implementing my own distribution to ensure that the output is deterministic regardless of library implementation?

Comment: Which randon number engine are you using?

Comment: @jbgs I've tested the output of various random engines and they are indeed working as advertised across various STL implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any option besides implementing my own distribution to ensure
>   that the output is deterministic regardless of library implementation?

There is no option besides implementing your own distribution to ensure that the output is deterministic regardless of library implementation.  While engines are deterministic, distributions are not.

Typical implementations for `uniform_int_distribution` will involve "rejection" algorithms which will repeatedly get a number from a URNG and if that result is not in the desired range, throw it away and try again.  Variations on that theme will optimize that algorithm by folding out of range values into in-range values so as to minimize rejections without biasing the acceptance range, as the simplistic `offset + lcg() % range` algorithm does.

Answer (score 1):

At least if an LCG is good enough for your purpose, the [`std::linear_congruential_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine) instantiated with some fixed constants your application provides should produce deterministic output.

```
typedef uint64_t number;
constexpr number a {1};
constexpr number c {2};
constexpr number m {3};
constexpr number seed {0};
std::linear_congruential_engine<number, a, c, m> lcg {seed};
std::uniform_int_distribution<number> dist {0, 1000};
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  std::cout << dist(lcg) << std::endl;
```

Note that I've intentionally picked silly values for `a`, `c` and `m` so not to take any side in the debate about what would make a good set of parameters.

Comment: LCG is one of the engines I have tested against, the PRNG itself is not the issue at hand, the distribution is where I am getting different outputs.

Comment: Oh, okay.  It might be easiest to use `offset + lcg() % range` in that case.  Lucky you only want uniform integer distributions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that was where I was going to be heading. At this point my primary concern is introducing bias, but hey it should work good enough for now and be trivial to replace at a later date.